# Javafx Reporting Tool Solution

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have to recreate my swing desktop application to javafx2 desktop. But on swing I used Jasper report for reporting part. Place the jasper output to JFrame for displaying report on same frame. But unfortunately I can't find best solution for this option on Javafx2. So I make a temporary solution. That's on jasper part make output as pdf and view the pdf on javafx apps (jpedalfx pdf viewer solution). Its not a best because, time consuming.. Any other solution. I don't like Webview  integration (http://localhost/myreport.jasper). Because its has additional apache server. is it right?

Any feasible solution for javafx new comers.

Answer (score 4):

Jasper can produce report in PDF, XML, HTML, CSV, XLS, RTF, TXT. 
You can:

- put report in HTML and present it in WebView
- put report to XML, load it with JAXB and use that to populate TableView
- parse any format and populate TableView
- took data as Java objects and populate TableView

Comment: Thanks Sergey. 'put report in HTML and present it in WebView' is one solution. But jasper export to HTML can't display at correct view. My Jasper report is complex. That has grand total, sub group total, sub reports. I think it can't afford TableView on present stage (i'm n't confident). If the TableView can have these properties like subgroups like bands, summary row, etc, why I am going to jasper report. Its just my output to TableView and try to export TableView to pdf and then print that. I just look on DataFx, that has lot of properties that ease editing option. Not for reporting.

Comment: You may want to split your complex report between several tableviews. Other from that I have no better suggestion.